# Beethoven thematic index

Tags: history, reference-request, beethoven

Where can I find a thematic index to the works of Beethoven? In many hymn books there is a tune which is supposed to be from one of his works, but I do not recognize it and would like to find out if it is from his output or not.

Comment: There are quite of few thematic catalogues of Beethoven's works available online (e.g. here: http://www.henle.com/us/detail/index.html?Title=Ludwig+van+Beethoven_2207), but if you don't know which Beethoven work you're looking for, you could end up searching for a *long* time. Have you tried putting the melody into http://www.musipedia.org ? Could you post the melody as part of your question? This would really help, as somebody might recognise it...

Comment: You must be talking about his "Ode to Joy" from his Symphony No. 9. Or something else?

Comment: Wikipedia is generally pretty good at providing lists like this, assuming all you want is a list. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven

Comment: On the other hand, what are the titles of some of the hymns which use this melody from Beethoven ?  As @user546 says, melody is likely to be "Ode to Joy", but some searching reveals that other melodies from Beethoven have also been adapted as hymn tunes.

Answer (score 1):

- There is an online index of some of his best-known themes: [Beethoven — Thematic Index](https://bestclassicaltunes.com/ThematicByComposer.aspx?composer=Beethoven).
- There is a complete index published by Henle: [Beethoven: Thematic-Bibliographical Catalogue of Works](https://www.henle.de/us/detail/?Title=Dorfm%C3%BCller/Gertsch/Ronge%3A%20Ludwig%20van%20Beethoven_2207). (This is a revised edition of the catalog cited below by Kinsky and Halm.)
- "The standard thematic and bibliographical catalogue of Beethoven's works" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalogues_of_Beethoven_compositions#Catalogues)): Kinsky, G. and H. Halm. [Das Werk Beethovens](https://www.amazon.de/Beethovens-Thematisch-bibliographisches-Kompositionen-abgeschlossen-herausgegeben/dp/B002B99XS8): thematisch-bibliographisches Verzeichnis seiner sämtlichen vollendeten Kompositionen. München: G. Henle, 1955. OCLC 334667. (Also published by Henle, but not the same as the one linked above.)

Both editions of Kinsky and Halm are widely available, particularly in university libraries.